# BB Download a XML from String url

Tags: c++, blackberry, blackberry-10

I figured how to use RapidXML a C++ Lib to parse pretty much everything from my XML provided by my API what I need to do now is actually get the XML on to my BlackBerry Dev Alpha B running a BB 10.2.0

What would be the proper way to download a XML file via String/url. Also any fellow developers here who made the transition from Android/Java to BB/C++ any recommendations on how to make the transition smoother.

Comment: You're working with Cascades or Core? Parsing in Cascades is really easy compared to Android, just use a DataSource, or [another option you might like](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/data_management_data_sources.html)

Comment: @BojanKogoj I'm working on a native app.

Comment: Both Cascades and Core are native. Check [the second example](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/data_access/using_data_source.html), which uses remote XML. You don't need to parse it, everything is in _data_ (in onDataLoaded). I'll give you example in the morning if no one else will

Comment: Qt includes various types of XML parsers too, no need for a external library. DataSource is not always perfect, depends very much on the XML structure if it is suitable or not.